# Laravel debugger shows old blade template?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have made a change to a blade template. When I enter the corresponding route in the browser I get the following error explanation:

[image]

The actual error message

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: lang (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/member/resources/views/about/benefits.blade.php)

is correct. I used an undefined variable. However, the image on the top right corner is a screen shot of an older version of the template. This has nothing to with the error. It even appears after clearing `app/storage/framework/views` manually or by using `php artisan view:clear`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Add a new line to `benefits.blade.php` and save it. I've had changes not sync to the Vagrant disk properly at times.

Comment: @ceejayoz adding a new line to `benefits.blade.php` and saving it does not help. I still get an correct error message witha  non matching screenshot.

Comment: Are you doing the clearing on the Vagrant box itself or locally?

Comment: @ceejayoz I executed `php artisan view:clear` at the vagrant box itself, but I locally deleted the files on my computer (I first used the command and after that I tried to locally delete it). But that was both after having the issue. Also when I corrected the undefined variable issue from my OP, another correct error was shown in the text, but the image is still not matching.

Comment: You're sure you're not just being confused by the code being the post-compilation version of the Blade template?

Comment: @ceejayoz I am not sure if I understand what you mean, but I am confused for sure. However, if you look at the image you see that the error is that the variable `lang`is not defined. But in the image line 201 is highlighted that does not contain a `lang` variable. Also on line 201 I have used `<?php ..` which you surly not use in a Blade template. I have removed `<?php ..` from the current Blade template and made the mistake of adding a not defined `lang` variable. The error is correct, just the image is misleading.

Comment: @ceejayoz ohhh I think I understand now. The template is post-compilated thats why there is `<?php ..` in it. And ups.. there is the variable `$lang`. My mistake. Sorry! Should I remove my question?

Comment: Yeah, a Blade template's instructions get turned into raw PHP by the Blade compiler. The code you're seeing is after that (automatic) process. No need to delete the question - I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output's a bit confusing because you're seeing the Blade template **after** it is compiled automatically down to raw PHP. Blade's instructions aren't PHP - PHP doesn't know what to do with it - so Laravel turns it *into* PHP.

So, in your template:

```
{{ $lang }}
```

gets turned into:

```
<?php echo e($lang); ?>
```

and *that's* what gets executed by PHP.